# dateJS is overwriting variables

Tags: javascript, datejs

I am just starting with dateJS and it seems like a great lib but I am obviously missing something (probably a stupid mistake) but in my function I need 3 dates: clickedDate, weekStart & weekEnd. But using dateJS I seem to be overwritting each variable.  Can someone please point out my mistake?

```
var clickDate = myDate;
    console.log(clickDate);
var weekStart = Date.parse(clickDate).last().monday();
    console.log(clickDate);
var weekEnd = Date.parse(clickDate).next().sunday();
    console.log(weekEnd);

console.log('break');   

console.log(clickDate);
console.log(weekStart);
console.log(weekEnd);
```

The console shows the following

```
Date {Wed Nov 30 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
Date {Mon Nov 28 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
Date {Sun Dec 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
break
Date {Sun Dec 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
Date {Sun Dec 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
Date {Sun Dec 04 2011 00:00:00 GMT-0700 (US Mountain Standard Time)}
```

Comment: [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) please. A great tool for JavaScript SSCCEs: http://jsfiddle.net. What is `myDate`, a string? BTW, did you _mean_ to `console.log(clickDate)` twice in a row?

Comment: [It works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/LJJKn/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't an issue with Datejs, but a feature(?) of JavaScript Date objects. In JavaScript, the Date object is mutable, and setting a `Date` object value to a new variable creates a reference to the original, not a new object.

This can be demonstrated using plain old JavaScript (no Datejs):

**Exmaple**

```
var a = new Date(2011, 0, 1);
var b = a;
var c = b;

console.log('a', a); // 1-Jan-2011
console.log('b', b); // 1-Jan-2011
console.log('c', c); // 1-Jan-2011

// setting only 'a' will cause 'b' and 'c' to update as well.
a.setDate(10);

console.log('a', a); // 10-Jan-2011
console.log('b', b); // 10-Jan-2011
console.log('c', c); // 10-Jan-2011
```

The way to work around this if using Datejs is by "cloning" the Date objects. The following sample demonstrates the use of the `.clone()` function on the 'b' and 'c' Date objects.

**Example**

```
var a = new Date(2011, 0, 1);
var b = a.clone(); // clone creates a new 'copy' of 'a'.
var c = b.clone();

console.log('a', a); // 1-Jan-2011
console.log('b', b); // 1-Jan-2011
console.log('c', c); // 1-Jan-2011

a.setDate(10);

console.log('a', a); // 10-Jan-2011
console.log('b', b); // 1-Jan-2011
console.log('c', c); // 1-Jan-2011
```

Running the above, you should see the final results of 'b' and 'c' still reflect their original values even though 'a' has changed.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Javascript *Date is mutable*, not immutable as stated. It is a reference type, correct. But reference vs value type is one aspect, while mutability is a completely different thing. If all were good, Date would be an (1.) immutable (2.) value type, as in .Net.